# How to format complete project source code in phpstorm?

Tags: phpstorm

I found reformatting php source code in phpstorm for particular file is Ctrl+Shift+Alt+L. But is there any way to do for whole project files?

Comment: Have you tried invoking that action on folder (hint: in Project View panel) ?? Try it ...

Comment: Yes. I tired. Not happening. :(

Comment: Worked for me (test project though)... No ideas then.

Comment: I am using 9.0.2 version.

Comment: There was an option before to reformat folders on right click but there isn't one now in any of JetBrains products.
 I also have the same problem i need to reformat large codebase.

Answer (score 33):

If you have issues opening the "reformat code" popup for multiple files, make sure that you don't have *any* open files as it'll otherwise only reformat the current open file (*edit*: sometimes - I still haven't been able to figure out *why* it allows you to reformat the entire code *sometimes*, but regardless, this fix will work if it doesn't allow you to).

You can simply right click any file on your file list and select "Close all".

[image: Close all files in PHPStorm 2016.3]

After you've done this, select the folder you want to reformat in the code view:

[image: Project overview in PHPStorm 2016.3]

Finally, with all files open you can now select "Reformat code" in the "Code" part of your main toolbar:

[image: Reformat Code toolbar item in in PHPStorm 2016.3]

You'll now get the regular popup that most guides seem to mention, but that's otherwise hidden for some reason:

[image: Reformat Code popup in PHPStorm 2016.3]

Comment: This works for me in phpstorm 2018.2 - and though it works great subdirectories, the option is disabled if I select more than one directory at the same level. not a massive issue, but something to be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

If you close all open code window and select a folder in the Project pane, you can use the keyboard shortcut or the Code->Refactor command and you'll get the dialog to reformat the code for the entire folder. This works in 2018.03, even for multiple subdirectories.